# Apple store not including my app to update list

Tags: ios

After update my app on apple store, old user aren't receiving any message to update it.
Apple store on one's phone shows the other apps demanding for update, but not mine.

Any ideas why it not appearing on the update list?

If one search for my app and click on update it does work, but my old users has no way to know  there is a newer version of my app available.

**EDIT:** None of the answer below was right. after research the issue I finally found the problem.

The first version of the app was set to worldwide and the new version is country restricted, since we knew it, we checked if the mobiles not receiving the update message was from aboard and they wasn't, excluding the possibility of it cause the issue.

But in fact, for apple, if you buy a Belgium iPhone, uses an Belgium sim card, register on Apple Store as Belgium account and associate a credit card from Spain, your phone will be considered Spanish. The credit card is the only matters.

So, the users not receiving the update message are the ones with a foreign credit card associated to their account.

Thank you everyone for try to help! I hope this question help someone.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about updates in Apple store and not about programming.

Comment: Hey easwee, it is a Apple Store question, you are right. Since Apple store is a "deploy" process for IOS, it still a IOS question worth to be in stackoverflow. Keep collaborating!

Answer (score 3):

If you updated your app within the last few hours, it may simply be that Apple hasn't indicized your app yet. Give it time.

Comment: I did update just two hours ago, I'll wait two days and update this post. thank you.

Comment: so that's definitely the reason, just wait a few more hours and it will be available ;)

Comment: Thank you Gabriele but was a country restriction issue, I just add the comments on the question. Keep collaborating!

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you have deployed the update for newer version of iOS than your previous users have on their iDevices - in that case, they aren't eligible for update. Or it's just too soon - give it a day or two.

Comment: Thank you Michal but was a country restriction issue, I just add the comments on the question

Comment: I see, well in the end, you found the solution, so gratz!